# Using For loop in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am not able to pass the variable ${ELEMENT} values in the Body it just takes the last value from the list.
I want to iterate it for all three values

```
Create Http Context    localhost:8080    http
Set Request Header    Content-Type    application/json
@{RecipientPhoneNumber} =    Create List    2162692764    21    2162792985
: FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{RecipientPhoneNumber}
\    Log    ${ELEMENT}
Set Request Body  {"id":"123456-789", "value":"${ELEMENT}"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put Set request body keyword inside for loop:

```
Create Http Context    localhost:8080    http
Set Request Header    Content-Type    application/json
@{RecipientPhoneNumber} =    Create List    2162692764    21    2162792985
: FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{RecipientPhoneNumber}
\    Log    ${ELEMENT}
\    Set Request Body  {"id":"123456-789", "value":"${ELEMENT}"}
```